# is there a good framework or example for integration test of multi topology with kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I finished an application with multi topologies, those topologies are linked with each other by their source and sink.

for example

```
topology1 -> topology2 -> topology3
```

with 'kafka-streams-test-utils', it is easy for the unit test with each topology, but I have no idea how to deal with the integration test.

Is there a framework or example for integration test with all topologies?

**`UPDATE:`**
I solved it by connecting all topologies via `through`

Comment: For testing, you could connect those topologies into one topology via `through()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for response too late,  I was confused about `topology` and `sub-topologies` before.   I can test all topologies with `throught` now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved it by connecting all topologies via through.